# unique description of a convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons, quadrilateral

I’m looking for a unique way to describe a convex quadrilateral.
The common way to express a quadrilateral is to give the four vertices: $[(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3), (x_4, y_4)]$. The problem I have is that if we know that we are looking for a convex quadrilateral, the order of the points doesn’t matter and thus $[(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3), (x_4, y_4)]$ describes the same quadrilateral than $[(x_2, y_2), (x_1, y_1), (x_3, y_3), (x_4, y_4)]$. Is there a better notation for a convex quadrilateral?

Comment: The order of the points certainly does matter if the quadrilateral is concave. (I assume by _simple_ you mean non-self-intersecting, so concave quadrilaterals are simple.)

Comment: We may be able to help more if you [edit] the question to provide some context. Why do you need a unique way to describe these non-intersecting quadrilaterals?

Comment: Oh yes you are right! I’m only dealing with convex quadrilateral though, I edited my question, thanks!

Comment: The representation of the polynomial will be used as the output of a neural network. For now I’m computing all the possible losses (the L1 distances (vertex-wise ) between the ground truth polynomial and all the permutations of the vertices of the predicted polynomial) and I take the smallest one.

Comment: Might be clearer to state that you are looking for a *canonical* representation of quadrilaterals, in order to ease the matching of two of them.

Comment: Do you allow degenerate quadrilaterals (i.e., two corners being the same, or all four corners lying on a single line, etc.)?

Comment: There is a smell of XY question. If your need is to find the best matching between two quadrilateral, you should ask that question, which seems easier.

Comment: Also: are you (as @dcolazin's answer suggests) looking for a *continuous* mapping to some target space like $\Bbb R^8$? If not, then sorting the points in lexicographic order is fine. If so, there may be some topological obstruction (which is why I asked about degenerate cases -- I'd like to understand the topology of the domain).

Comment: @TonyK: Of course, you're right. My comment, as written, is embarrassingly false; thanks for the correction. ... I was thinking specifically that OP had a particular set of coordinates that already defined a convex quadrilateral, and wanted some assurance that the quadrilateral could be recovered if the order of the vertices had changed. The point of my comment was supposed to be simply that convex hulls don't care about order.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to order the four vertices in the same traversal order (it is a simple matter to determine the convex hull of four points). Doing so, you reduce the number of permutations from $24$ to $4$.

---

To describe the quadrilateral, you need 8 parameters, as there are 8 degrees of freedom. The following ones are order independent:

- coordinates of the centroid (the mass can be uniform, uniform along edges or concentrated at vertices);
- higher order moments;
- coordinates of the intersection of the diagonals;
- area;
- perimeter;
- shortest and longest side;
- shortest and longest diagonal;
- ratios of the above;
- directions of the above segments (in range $[0,\pi)$).

Comment: A nice list. I'm assuming that by "shortest side," you mean "length of shortest side" (although the vector (mod $\pm 1$) along the side is also order independent). I have one concern, which is that the direction of the shortest and longest diagonal are not well-defined for rectangles (because the two diagonals are equal in length, so either could be the "shortest"). If the OP wants a continuous map to the space of representations, this could be a problem.

Comment: @JohnHughes: right, there is no perfect solution (and I do mean length of…)

Comment: What do you mean by "determine the convex hull"? What would be the output of such a determination?

Comment: @TonyK: ordered vertices.

Answer (score 0):

A way is to define a total order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ so the order of the points $p_1, \ldots, p_4$ is determined. For example $(x_1, y_1) < (x_2, y_2) \iff (x_1 < x_2)$ or $(x_1 = x_2, y_1 < y_2)$. Then the representation is $(p_1, \ldots, p_4)$ with $p_1 < p_2 < p_3 < p_4$.

A worst(?) way (I don't know if the neural network will be able to learn this representation) is: point of intersection of the diagonals, the angle between the $x$ axis and the "first" (counterclockwise, for example) diagonal, the angle between diagonals, length of the first diagonal , length of the second diagonal.

As TonyK noted in a comment, this kind of representation is not really robust. Using a loss similar to the [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) might be more useful than a $L^p$ loss between vertices.

To better understand if the second representation can be actually used in real life applications, it might me interesting to study how "non-rectangular" bounding boxes are represented. Maybe a study of the literature about [regionlets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.02408.pdf) can help you.

Comment: The trouble with your first suggestion is that it is very sensitive to small changes: if $A$ and $B$ have nearly the same $x$-coordinate, then $A,B,C,D$ can become $B,A,C,D$ if $A$ or $B$ change only slightly. This is no good for scoring the output of a neural network. (Not that I have a better suggestion.)

Comment: @TonyK Maybe the loss shouldn't be a distance between the points, but something like Area(predicted $\cup$ ground truth) - Area(ground truth $\cap$ predicted) (the IoU https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). But your comment is really important!

Comment: Your second method has the same drawback: the choice of "first" diagonal is sensitive to small changes.

Comment: @TonyK and again, you are right!

Comment: OP did not ask for a continuous mapping to the representation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had considered simply sorting the points as you suggested but as @TonyK said the problem is: a very small change in the quadrilateral can lean to a hug change of the neural network outputs which is really not neural network friendly.

Comment: @Neabfi maybe a more friendly order is: $(x,y) < (z,w) \iff \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \sqrt{z^2 + w^2}$ or ($\sqrt{\ldots} = \sqrt{\ldots}$ and $x < z$)

Answer (score 0):

As the answers here show, there doesn't seem to be an elegant representation of quadrilaterals that gives you a simple expression for the difference between them. So brute force is probably the best solution. But it's not so expensive. Here is how I would do it:

1. Get the quadrilaterals in clockwise form, $ABCD$ and $EFGH$.
2. We define the distance between $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ to be
   $$|A-E|^2+|B-F|^2+|C-G|^2+|D-H|^2$$
   (the squaring makes the arithmetic much simpler). So this is
   $$(x_A-x_E)^2+(y_A-y_E)^2+(x_B-x_F)^2+(y_B-y_F)^2+(x_C-x_G)^2+(y_C-y_G)^2+(x_D-x_H)^2+(y_D-y_H)^2$$
   $$=\sum_{i\in\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\}}(x_i^2+y_i^2)-2(x_Ax_E+y_Ay_E+x_Bx_F+y_By_F+x_Cx_G+y_Cy_G+x_Dx_H+y_Dy_H)$$
   The nice thing about this is that the sum of squares is independent of the choice of $EFGH$. So you only need to compute it once.
3. Compute the above for the four quadrilaterals $EFGH, FGHE, GHEF,$ and $HEFG$. Take the minimum. And in fact if all you need to know is which is the best, you don't even need to compute that sum of squares.

I realise that step 1 is not as simple as all that, whatever Yves Daoust says. Can you assume that your neural network outputs quadrilaterals in clockwise form? Or at least in consecutive (i.e. clockwise or anticlockwise) form? If not, let me know in the comments, and I will try to expand step 1.

Answer (score -1):

For a convex quadrilateral, an unordered set of four points $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3), (x_4,y_4) \}$ defines a quadrilateral uniquely, so this notation is fine.

For a concave quadrilateral however, four points do not determine the quadrilateral uniquely, so you can do a couple of things.

1) You can order the points $((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3), (x_4,y_4) )$ and define the quadrilateral they represent by starting at the first point, then drawing a line to the second, then to the third, to the fourth, and then back to the first. 
or,

2) You can represent the edges of the quadrilateral (but this is a bit longer) in the form $\{ \{(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)\},\{(x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3)\},\{(x_3,y_3), (x_4,y_4)\},\{(x_4,y_4), (x_1,y_1)\} \}$. (You only need to store 3 edges in fact, as the last will be uniquely determined)

Comment: The quadrilateral is known to be convex.